# How can I set up geoIP2 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, geoip, maxmind

A client is asking me to setup geoip javascript in his JQuery file

the problem is that I have no idea how! I only used javascript for effects and never for databases or such other things

I tried their tutorial but got no idea where to put the key they gave me!

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Jason from MaxMind here. You don't need to use the key with the GeoIP2 JavaScript API. You do however need to register your domain.

See http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/#Registration

Comment: Hey Jason, I just spent two-three hours also trying to figure out how to set my key in the Javascript API before finally falling upon this obscure post.   Could you please update the documentation here (https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/) to explicitly say the key is not required, to save the next poor person from having the same problem?   It's not at all clear from the wording that the key is unnecessary